# If S is orthonormal and $y \in span (S)$, then $y=\sum_{i=1}^{k}<y,v_i> v_i$.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Corollary:If S is orthonormal and $y \in span (S)$, then $y=\sum_{i=1}^{k} \langle y,v_i \rangle v_i$.

What's the general idea of proving this?

attempt: since $y \in span(S)$, then it is a linear combination of $\sum_{i=1}^{k} c_i v_i$ where $c_i$ is a scalar $\in F$. How am I supposed to prove that $c_i=\langle y,v_i \rangle$ from the ground up? What fact to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_iv_i$for some scalars $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$. Take inner product with $v_j$ to get $\langle y, v_j \rangle =a_j$ in  view of orthonormality.

Comment: why do we take inner product with $v_j$? Orthogonality?

Comment: It helps you find the value of $a_j$. @neveryield

Comment: Inner product $\langle v ,e_j\rangle$ is the projection of $v$ onto $e_j$, and quantifies "how much of $v$ points in the direction of $e_j$. Thus in the above sum, you are saying that $v$ is given by an object pointing $\langle v , e_1\rangle$ magnitude in the direction of $e_1$, $\langle v , e_2\rangle$ magnitude in the direction of $e_2$, and so forth.

Comment: @rubikscube09 appreciate it!